# Laravel 9 - Attempt to read property "nom_prenoms" on null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

I have two models as follows.

Tier Model:

```
public function contact(){
    return $this->belongsTo(ContactAdresse::class,"contact_adresse_id");
}
```

ContactAdresse Model:

```
public function tiers(){
    return $this->hasMany(Tier::class);
}
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve the Tier associated with the Contact using this code:

```
{{ $ContactAdresse->tier->nom_prenoms}}
```

I have the following error.

> Attempt to read property "nom_prenoms" on null

Does anyone have an idea, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the `nom_prenoms` property of each `Tier` associated with a `ContactAdresse`, you can loop through the `tiers` collection like this.

```
@foreach($ContactAdresse->tiers as $tier)
    {{ $tier->nom_prenoms }}
@endforeach
```